# Hibernate: Query cache never used

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, orm, jpa

During performing some performance tuning in my application I have noticed, that hibernate query cache is never used.

I am quite sure I have it properly set up:

- hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
- hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
- I use `setCacheable(true)` on queries I want to cache

I have set up a simple stress test, when I perform the same set of operations over and over by several threads. When I check hibernate statistics it turns out that query cache hitCount is zero!

What am I missing?

EDIT:
For all of you asking: I have set `hibernate.generate_statistics = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have set up a simple stress test, when I perform the same set of operations over and over by several threads. When I check hibernate statistics it turns out that query cache hitCount is zero!

Well, while it is possible to get statistics about cache hits from statistics (**if** you enable statistics by setting the property `hibernate.generate_statistics=true` in your configuration), this is IMO not the best way to diagnose caching "issues".

My suggestion would be to activate the logging of 1. the DML statements that are executed and of 2. the cache activity. The relevant logging categories are:

- `org.hibernate.SQL`   Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
- `org.hibernate.cache` Log all second-level cache activity

This is IMO more useful  than statistics **to fine tune the behavior** during development.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Documentation

  - [3.4.6. Hibernate statistics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-statistics)
  - [3.5 Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I analyzed the logs, turned out much of the queries I presumed to be cached, were not. Also a caught a couple of simple mistakes like using new Date() as parameter value. It works way better now.

Answer (score 1):

Though you do not mention it, you have also set `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true|false`?

Comment: I this necessary? I though hibernate.cache.provider_class set is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not gather statistics by default. Have you enabled statistics?

- hibernate.generate_statistics = true